# cases - change case roles

Tags: civicase

I try to change the role of a case.
 - Case coordinator (case manager) is manuel berger.
 - I click on reassign case coordinator
 - Enter a new name and click save

then the following error massage appears:
"The relationship type definition for the case role is not valid for the client and / or staff contact types. You can review and edit relationship types at Administer >> Option Lists >> Relationship Types.

Is there a solution to change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is your client an organization or individual? I know at one time it only worked with individual-individual, but I thought that was updated, but maybe not. I get the same error when I try on the public demo (4.6) with an org client.

Comment: it is an organisation

Comment: Try adding a new relationship type that is org-to-individual and updating the civicase config to use it for the manager.

Answer (score 3):

I think Demerit's answer of adding org-to-individual should work.  However, i'd thought i'd add some other considerations for anyone searching.

I've had this problem before, especially when using multi-client case setup.

I found that if there was a mismatch between any of the clients contact type/subtype with the new caseworker's contact type/subtype then i got this message.

This was further compounded by some users trying to add invalid contacts (e.g. a household) as clients to the case.

Steps to check

- Contact type/subtype of each client(s) involved in a case
- Contact type/subtype of the new case manager
- Check all combinations are valid
- If you're doing this with bulk import data there could be an issue missing data e.g. contact subtype.

I found the solution by

1. reviewing relationship types **Administer >> Option Lists >> Relationship Types**
2. Setting them to **individual - individual** (they were 
   the more narrow **"contact sub-type A - contact sub-type B")**.  This lessend the chance of a conflict
3. Amend the case open form or webform to limit the contact types that can be added as clients to limit only to valid contact types.